# CSS Same Height Columns with One Column Containg Bottom Div

Tags: html, css

I'm desperate to not use tables (not that tables will work) but we have a situation where the user wants 3 column divs floating with one div having two divs, one of which needs to be displayed at bottom of the div.

Maybe I need to rethink the whole process and persuade user to  keep it simple.

Anyway here is my code:

```
<style>
    #outer-div {
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: grey;
    }
    #column-one {
        padding-bottom: 500em;
        margin-bottom: -500em;
        background-color: red;
        width: 200px;
        float: left;
    }
    #column-two {
        padding-bottom: 500em;
        margin-bottom: -500em;
        background-color: green;
        width: 200px;
        float: left;
    }
    #column-three {
        padding-bottom: 500em;
        margin-bottom: -500em;
        background-color: blue;
        width: 200px;
        float: left;
    }
    #column-one-bottom {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        background-color: pink;
    }
</style>
<div id="outer-div">
    <div id="column-one">
        <div id="column-one-top">
            Column One Top Data<br/>
            Column One Top Data<br/>
            Column One Top Data<br/>
            Column One Top Data<br/>
            Column One Top Data<br/>
        </div>
        <div id="column-one-bottom">
            Column One Bottom Data
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="column-two">
        Column Two Data<br/>
        Column Two Data<br/>
        Column Two Data<br/>
        Column Two Data<br/>
        Column Two Data<br/>
        Column Two Data<br/>
        Column Two Data<br/>
        Column Two Data<br/>
        Column Two Data<br/>
        Column Two Data<br/>
    </div>
    <div id="column-three">
        Column Three Data<br/>
        Column Three Data<br/>
        Column Three Data<br/>
        Column Three Data<br/>
    </div>
    <br style="clear: both;"/>
</div>
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/Zre8D/2/

Hope someone can help.

The problems is with #column-one-bottom. I need this to be bottom of it's parent, not middle of div.

Comment: ummm can u provide a screenshot?

Comment: How do i provide a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

```css
#column-one-bottom {
    position: absolute;
```

Try:

```css
#column-one-bottom {
    position: relative;
```

Comment: Thanks, tried that, it puts the div middle of column. Needs to be at bottom of parent div.

Comment: I dont follow you. Can you post a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ? http://jsfiddle.net/Zre8D/

HTML:

```
<div id="outer-div">
    <div id="column-one">
        <div id="column-one-top">
            Column One Top Data<br/>
            Column One Top Data<br/>
            Column One Top Data<br/>
            Column One Top Data<br/>
            Column One Top Data<br/>
        </div>
        <div id="column-one-bottom">
            Column One Bottom Data
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="column-two">
        Column Two Data<br/>
        Column Two Data<br/>
        Column Two Data<br/>
        Column Two Data<br/>
        Column Two Data<br/>
        Column Two Data<br/>
        Column Two Data<br/>
        Column Two Data<br/>
        Column Two Data<br/>
        Column Two Data<br/>
    </div>
    <div id="column-three">
        Column Three Data<br/>
        Column Three Data<br/>
        Column Three Data<br/>
        Column Three Data<br/>
    </div>
    <br style="clear: both;"/>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
#outer-div {
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: grey;
    }
    #column-one {
        background-color: red;
        width: 200px;
        float: left;
        position:relative;
        padding-bottom:200px;
    }
    #column-two {
        background-color: green;
        width: 200px;
        float: left;
    }
    #column-three {
        background-color: blue;
        width: 200px;
        float: left;
    }
    #column-one-bottom {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        background-color: pink;
        overflow:hidden;
    }​
```

Comment: i did remove margin and padding specified in em. Didn't make sense to me. But if you need it, can you explain why ?

Comment: Thanks... however the column two and three are not 100% height, so you end up seeing the grey (trying to avoid seeing any grey :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your style as follow.

```
<style>
    #outer-div 
    {
        height: 100%;
        background-color: grey;
    }
    #column-one 
    {
        background-color: red;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        width: 200px;
        height: 100%
    }
    #column-two 
    {
        background-color: green;
        width: 200px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 200;
        height: 100%
    }
    #column-three {
        background-color: blue;
        width: 200px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 400;
        height: 100%
    }
    #column-one-bottom {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        background-color: pink;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks, however if you add a couple or more <br/>'s in column 2, it breaks the column-one-bottom.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the solution. Was close to the solution (http://jsfiddle.net/Zre8D/12/):

```
#outer-div {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: grey;
    position: relative;
}
#column-one {
    padding-bottom: 500em;
    margin-bottom: -500em;
    background-color: red;
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
}
#column-two {
    padding-bottom: 500em;
    margin-bottom: -500em;
    background-color: green;
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
}
#column-three {
    padding-bottom: 500em;
    margin-bottom: -500em;
    background-color: blue;
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
}
#column-one-bottom {
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: pink;
}
```